# How to write select query for column with XML as Datatype in DB2?

Tags: sql, xml, select, db2

How to write select query for column with XML as Datatype in DB2?

I am using DB2 9.7

Comment: Just like any other query, I should think.

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
Select XMLSERIALIZE(tab.EXTENSION_XML  as BLOB(1M))  from TABLE tab;
```

[Link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0511melnyk/)